# delete() not working on Eloquent in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

delete() not working on Eloquent in laravel and getting the call to member function error. Like is just a simple model.

```
  $matchThese = ['snippet_id' => $snippet_id, 'user_id' => $user_id];
  $likedsnippet =  Like::where($matchThese)->get();
  $likedsnippet->delete();
```

Comment: send your error message here.

Answer (score 1):

Is Like has a child, or attached relationship? If yes, you first need to detach the connection or delete the child object as well.

If Like is a simple object, is it exists at all?

Maybe the object with the conditions you are searching for does not exists. Try to dd the like object before the delete, or wrap it around with:

```
if(isset($likedsnippet))
{
   $likedsnippet->delete();
}
```

Or you can try to delete the objects one by one using a foreach:

```
foreach($likedsnippet as $obj)
{
   $obj->delete();
}
```

Comment: Updated my question(Like is just simple Model)

Comment: and I updated my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent's `get` method return an `Collection` instance and collections don't have `delete` method. You can rewrite the query like this:

```php
Like::where($matchThese)->delete();
```

it looks like there are only one deleting model in your application, if it's So, you can use `first` method.

```php
  $likedsnippet = Like::where($matchThese)->first();
  $likedsnippet->delete();
```